# Error Message Not Displayed Properly and Wrong Input gets selected

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using **jquery** **select2** method for multiple selections and for users to enter their own input it uses tags property.

Now I want to display the error message when a user enters wrong input.

Therefore, I am using **formatResult** property of **select2** and checking **regex** for input.

When the input is correct; it returns the input else it returns error message from the function.

But this message is not coming in the format as it comes for select2 example "No matches found" and even when the error message is displayed, on clicking enter it takes the wrong input.

I want to display the message in correct format and not to select the wrong input on enter.

Please help. Below is my code:

```
$("#abc").select2({ 
  minimumInputLength:1,
  maximumInputLength:10, 
  formatResult: function(term){ 
     if(term.text === 0) 
       return "Zero Not Allowed"; 
     else return term.text; 
    }});
```

In this code, "zero not allowed" is not coming in the same format as "Please enter 1 or more characters" and when we press enter, zero gets selected.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: you should edit your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: $("#abc").select2({ minimumInputLength:1, maximumInputLength:10, formatResult: function(term){ if(term.text === 0) return "Zero Not Allowed"; else  return term.text; }}); In this code, "zero not allowed" is not coming in the same format as "Please enter 1 or more characters" and when we press enter, zero gets selected.